# How to store data in the next Null value column in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I am in the process of creating a database for a tournament tracking software, part of which involves storing the ID of a user as a value to reference later on. To do this, I am using 2 tables; *player*(primary key *player_ID*), which stores information about a player in an event, such as their *user_ID* (Part of an unrelated table) and the results of the matches they have played, and *event*, which stores all event details, as well as the *player_ID* of all 16 event participants. These columns are named *player1* -> *player16*

My issue arises with trying to find a way to fill these columns individually. When the event is created, all 16 columns begin with value Null, and will be changed to the *player_ID* created in the *player* table when a user registers for the event.

My first thought was to create individual queries for each of the columns to sequentially check if they contained a non-Null value, then update the first column to match this criteria and break out of the check, however it seems highly inefficient to have 32 queries to cover every option. Is there a way to compact this to a more reasonable size, and if so, how would I do so?

Answer (score 0):

It would be suggested that you consider a third table, this being a map (associative table, reference table, mapping table and other terms) to map players to events and no issue/complications when adding another player to an event other than limiting to 16 per event (which is relatively simple).

Such a table supports a **many-many** relationship. That is an event could have many players and a player could be in many events.

Such a table consists of 2 primary columns, one to reference the event and the other to reference the player. The primary key should typically consist of both these columns (so a player cannot be in the same event).

Initially an event will have no players and players can be added. The only issue would be limiting to 16 players to an event, which simply means checking the number of players in the event (demo SELECT QUERY includes obtaining the count).

Here's a demo:-

```
/* just in case cleanup the environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS event_participant;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS player;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS event;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player (player_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, player_name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event (event_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, event_name TEXT /* etc */);
/* THE MAPPING TABLE */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event_participant (
    event_id_map INTEGER REFERENCES event(event_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    player_id_map INTEGER REFERENCES player(player_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (event_id_map,player_id_map));
    /* Note FOREIGN KEY (aka REFERENCES) is optional but suggested as it enforces referential integrity */
        /* ON DELETE and ON UPDATE are optional but help to maintain referential integrity again suggested */
/* SUGGESTED INDEX ON the 2nd column, will liekly improve efficiency */
CREATE INDEX ix_event_participant_playermap ON event_participant (player_id_map);
/* ADD SOME DATA */
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO player (player_name) VALUES('Mary'),('Jane'),('Tom'),('Fred'),('Anne'),('Bert'),('Alan'),('Beth');
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO event (event_name) VALUES('E1'),('E2'),('E3'),('E4');
/* NOTHING SELECTED as there are currently no events with participants */
SELECT 
    event_name,
    group_concat(player_name,'::') AS players,
    count(*) AS num_of_players 
FROM event
    JOIN event_participant ON event.event_id = event_participant.event_id_map
    JOIN player ON player_id_map = player_id
GROUP BY event_id
ORDER BY num_of_players
/* Add some participants to some events */
;
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO event_participant VALUES
    (1,2),(1,4),(1,8) /* Jane, Fred and Beth in event 1*/,
    (2,1),(2,3),(2,5),(2,7) /* Mary, Tom, Anne and Alan in event 2 */,
    (3,1),(3,4),(3,8),(3,6),(3,2),(3,7),(3,5),(3,3) /* all in event 3 note any order */,
    /*!!!!!!!!!! OOOPS ON PURPOSE !!!!!!!!!!*/ (1,2),(1,4),(1,8) /* Jane, Fred and Beth in event 1??????????*/
    /* ooops because they already exist as participants in the event */ 
;
/* Now there are participants then the exact same query as above will yield results */
SELECT 
    event_name,
    group_concat(player_name,'::') AS players,
    count(*) AS num_of_players 
FROM event
    JOIN event_participant ON event.event_id = event_participant.event_id_map
    JOIN player ON player_id_map = player_id
GROUP BY event_id
ORDER BY num_of_players
;
/* Cleanup demo environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS event_participant;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS player;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS event;
```

When run then the message log shows:-

```
/* just in case cleanup the environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS event_participant
> OK
> Time: 0.323s


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS player
> OK
> Time: 0.041s


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS event
> OK
> Time: 0.024s


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player (player_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, player_name TEXT)
> OK
> Time: 0.024s


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event (event_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, event_name TEXT /* etc */)
> OK
> Time: 0.024s


/* THE MAPPING TABLE */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event_participant (
    event_id_map INTEGER REFERENCES event(event_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    player_id_map INTEGER REFERENCES player(player_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (event_id_map,player_id_map))
> OK
> Time: 0.024s


/* Note FOREIGN KEY (aka REFERENCES) is optional but suggested as it enforces referential integrity */
        /* ON DELETE and ON UPDATE are optional but help to maintain referential integrity again suggested */
/* SUGGESTED INDEX ON the 2nd column, will liekly improve efficiency */
CREATE INDEX ix_event_participant_playermap ON event_participant (player_id_map)
> OK
> Time: 0.024s


/* ADD SOME DATA */
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO player (player_name) VALUES('Mary'),('Jane'),('Tom'),('Fred'),('Anne'),('Bert'),('Alan'),('Beth')
> Affected rows: 8
> Time: 0.024s


INSERT OR IGNORE INTO event (event_name) VALUES('E1'),('E2'),('E3'),('E4')
> Affected rows: 4
> Time: 0.024s


/* NOTHING SELECTED as there are currently no events with participants */
SELECT 
    event_name,
    group_concat(player_name,'::') AS players,
    count(*) AS num_of_players 
FROM event
    JOIN event_participant ON event.event_id = event_participant.event_id_map
    JOIN player ON player_id_map = player_id
GROUP BY event_id
ORDER BY num_of_players
/* Add some participants to some events */
> OK
> Time: 0s


INSERT OR IGNORE INTO event_participant VALUES
    (1,2),(1,4),(1,8) /* Jane, Fred and Beth in event 1*/,
    (2,1),(2,3),(2,5),(2,7) /* Mary, Tom, Anne and Alan in event 2 */,
    (3,1),(3,4),(3,8),(3,6),(3,2),(3,7),(3,5),(3,3) /* all in event 3 note any order */,
    /*!!!!!!!!!! OOOPS ON PURPOSE !!!!!!!!!!*/ (1,2),(1,4),(1,8) /* Jane, Fred and Beth in event 1??????????*/
    /* ooops because they already exist as participants in the event */
> Affected rows: 15
> Time: 0.024s


/* Now there are participants then the exact same query as above will yield results */
SELECT 
    event_name,
    group_concat(player_name,'::') AS players,
    count(*) AS num_of_players 
FROM event
    JOIN event_participant ON event.event_id = event_participant.event_id_map
    JOIN player ON player_id_map = player_id
GROUP BY event_id
ORDER BY num_of_players
> OK
> Time: 0s


/* Cleanup demo environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS event_participant
> OK
> Time: 0.023s


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS player
> OK
> Time: 0.024s


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS event
> OK
> Time: 0.052s
```

The result of the first query (i.e. nothing):-

[image]

The result of the second query (i.e. when events have participants) :-

[image]

First there are 3 rows because there is the `GROUP BY` clause on the event_id. i.e. all rows that have the same event_id value are grouped together as a single output row.

As can be seen the rows are `ORDER`ed by the number of participants in an event the lower number being output first (as the default order is `ASC`ending).

The **number of players** is exactly that and utilises the SQLite aggregate `count` function. see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#count

The **players** column again uses an SQLite aggregate function, this time though the `group_concat` function, which concatenates the value from the expression passed to it with all the other values for each row in the group. see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#group_concat

- note that `JOIN` in the `SELECT` demonstrates two forms of specifying columns. One form is the table name separated from the column name by a period, thus fully qualifying the column name. The second form is just the column name. This latter form is shorter and easier **BUT** is subject to ambiguity.
- e.g. if the 'event_id' and 'player_id' columns were instead named just  `id` then using the column name id would be ambiguos and result in an error.

---

**Alternately**

---

An alternative, not using a mapping table could be utilise CASE WHEN THEN END clauses.

Consider this demo, that progressively fills null columns in an event
table. ***Noting that the exact same `UPDATE` is used throughout BUT that the player passed (hard coded but would be passed/bound upon invocation (as would the id of the event used in the WHERE clause)):-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS player;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS event;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player (player_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, player_name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event (event_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, event_name TEXT, 
    p1 INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    p2 INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    p3 INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    p4 INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    p5 INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    p6 INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
);
INSERT INTO player VALUES (1,'Fred'),(2,'Mary'),(3,'Anne'),(4,'Tom'),(5,'Jane'),(6,'Alan'),(7,'Joe'),(8,'Sue'),(9,'Jan');
INSERT INTO event (event_id,event_name) VALUES (10,'E1'),(11,'E2');

WITH cte(new_player) AS (SELECT 1 /* id of new player to add to the event passed by invocation */)
UPDATE event
    SET 
        p1 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p1 END,
        p2 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p2 END,
        p3 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p3 END,
        p4 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NOT NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p4 END,
        p5 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NOT NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p5 END,
        p6 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NOT NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p6 END
WHERE event_id = 10 /* value would be set (bound) by invocation */
;
SELECT * FROM event;

WITH cte(new_player) AS (SELECT 5 /* id of new player to add to the event passed by invocation */)
UPDATE event
    SET 
        p1 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p1 END,
        p2 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p2 END,
        p3 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p3 END,
        p4 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NOT NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p4 END,
        p5 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NOT NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p5 END,
        p6 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NOT NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p6 END
WHERE event_id = 10 /* value would be set (bound) by invocation */
;
SELECT * FROM event;

WITH cte(new_player) AS (SELECT 3 /* id of new player to add to the event passed by invocation */)
UPDATE event
    SET 
        p1 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p1 END,
        p2 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p2 END,
        p3 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p3 END,
        p4 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NOT NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p4 END,
        p5 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NOT NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p5 END,
        p6 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NOT NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p6 END
WHERE event_id = 10 /* value would be set (bound) by invocation */
;
SELECT * FROM event;

WITH cte(new_player) AS (SELECT 2 /* id of new player to add to the event passed by invocation */)
UPDATE event
    SET 
        p1 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p1 END,
        p2 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p2 END,
        p3 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p3 END,
        p4 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NOT NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p4 END,
        p5 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NOT NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p5 END,
        p6 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NOT NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p6 END
WHERE event_id = 10 /* value would be set (bound) by invocation */
;
SELECT * FROM event;


WITH cte(new_player) AS (SELECT 1 /* id of new player to add to the event passed by invocation */)
UPDATE event
    SET 
        p1 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p1 END,
        p2 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p2 END,
        p3 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p3 END,
        p4 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NOT NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p4 END,
        p5 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NOT NULL AND p4 IS NOT NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p5 END,
        p6 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NOT NULL AND p4 IS NOT NULL AND p5 IS NOT NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p6 END
WHERE event_id = 10 /* value would be set (bound) by invocation */
;
SELECT * FROM event;

WITH cte(new_player) AS (SELECT 99 /* id of new player to add to the event passed by invocation */)
UPDATE event
    SET 
        p1 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p1 END,
        p2 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p2 END,
        p3 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p3 END,
        p4 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NOT NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p4 END,
        p5 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NOT NULL AND p4 IS NOT NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p5 END,
        p6 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NOT NULL AND p4 IS NOT NULL AND p5 IS NOT NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p6 END
WHERE event_id = 10 /* value would be set (bound) by invocation */
;
SELECT * FROM event;


WITH cte(new_player) AS (SELECT 666 /* id of new player to add to the event passed by invocation */)
UPDATE event
    SET 
        p1 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p1 END,
        p2 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p2 END,
        p3 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p3 END,
        p4 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NOT NULL AND p4 IS NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p4 END,
        p5 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NOT NULL AND p4 IS NOT NULL AND p5 IS NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p5 END,
        p6 = CASE WHEN p1 IS NOT NULL AND p2 IS NOT NULL AND p3 IS NOT NULL AND p4 IS NOT NULL AND p5 IS NOT NULL AND p6 IS NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM cte) ELSE p6 END
WHERE event_id = 10 /* value would be set (bound) by invocation */
;
SELECT * FROM event;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS player;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS event;
```

The results, in order, as per the SELECT queries, being:-

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

and finally after an attempt to add a seventh, with a player as 666  (i.e. the event is already full), that the player is not applied:-

- use is made of a **C**ommon **T**able **E**xpression (which suits the demo rather than hard coding the same value throughout, using the same bound value could circumvent this);

  - see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

---

** A little more complex but a little more compact** aka multiple CTE's

---

This example takes the above a stage further using multiple CTE's, so is more complex but a little less prone to coding errors (with the `IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL` coding.

The example is based upon the same 2 tables **event** and **player** as previously used and loaded.

The SQL being:-

```
WITH 
    cte_values(eid,pid) AS (SELECT 10 /*<<<<< event id to update */,1 /* player id to apply to first NULL column */),
    cte_current_state(ord,flag) AS (
        SELECT 1,coalesce(p1,0) FROM event WHERE event_id = (SELECT eid FROM cte_values)
            UNION SELECT 2,coalesce(p2,0) FROM event WHERE event_id = (SELECT eid FROM cte_values)
            UNION SELECT 3,coalesce(p3,0) FROM event WHERE event_id = (SELECT eid FROM cte_values)
            UNION SELECT 4,coalesce(p4,0) FROM event WHERE event_id = (SELECT eid FROM cte_values)
            UNION SELECT 5,coalesce(p5,0) FROM event WHERE event_id = (SELECT eid FROM cte_values)
            UNION SELECT 6,coalesce(p6,0) FROM event WHERE event_id = (SELECT eid FROM cte_values)
        ),
    cte_free_column AS (SELECT min(ord) AS ord FROM cte_current_state WHERE flag = 0)
UPDATE event SET 
    p1 = CASE WHEN (SELECT ord FROM cte_free_column) = 1 THEN (SELECT pid FROM cte_values) ELSE p1 END,
    p2 = CASE WHEN (SELECT ord FROM cte_free_column) = 2 THEN (SELECT pid FROM cte_values) ELSE p2 END,
    p3 = CASE WHEN (SELECT ord FROM cte_free_column) = 3 THEN (SELECT pid FROM cte_values) ELSE p3 END,
    p4 = CASE WHEN (SELECT ord FROM cte_free_column) = 4 THEN (SELECT pid FROM cte_values) ELSE p4 END,
    p5 = CASE WHEN (SELECT ord FROM cte_free_column) = 5 THEN (SELECT pid FROM cte_values) ELSE p5 END,
    p6 = CASE WHEN (SELECT ord FROM cte_free_column) = 6 THEN (SELECT pid FROM cte_values) ELSE p6 END
WHERE event_id = (SELECT eid FROM cte_values);
```

- Note that the first CTE (cte_values) is supplied the id of the event to be updated and the id of the player to be applied (again only if there is a free column).
- The second CTE **cte_current_state** generates a table with a row per column in the event table (as is hard coded, so 16 columns would need another 10 UNION SELECTS). The generated table has two columns **ord** which is the column order (i.e. p1 is 1, p2 is 2 and so on) and **flag** which is either 0 (indicating NULL in the respective column in the event tables row for the event id being processed/updated). So in the example/demo there will be 6 rows output.
- The third CTE **cte_free_column** extracts the **ord** (column indicator) from a single row of the **cte_current_state**. The single row being the row who's **ord** value is the lowest of those rows that have **flag** as 0 (i.e. the respective column is null).

The first (event to update via the eid column and the player id to set the respective column) and third CTE (used to determine which column, if any, is to be updated) are used to drive the update.

Using multiple invocations to progressively fill an event (similar to the previous example) with SELECT's after each results in (note that the player id used are different but 666 is still used for the attempt after all columns have been filled). The results of the SELECTS being:-

[image]

- immediately after the even table is created and before an UPDATE
  [image]
- after the 1st UPDATE
  [image]
- after the 2nd update
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
- all columns have been set, so an attempt to overfill:-
  [image]
- player id 666 has not been applied as the event is already full.

Here's a link to DB Fiddle with the full SQL code for this last example - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i8BtXgUwBX6T5wEJpbYWYd/0